# Document ID Being Duplicated in SharePoint Online Library

Tags: sharepoint-online

Has anyone else experienced an issue with Document ID's being duplicated in a **SharePoint Online** document library (classic experience)?

**Scenario:**
User downloads a copy of an Excel file/template from Lib 1.
Excel file is populated, then uploaded to Lib 2.
Some, but not all of the document IDs from the original Excel files are being duplicated in Lib 2.

Lib 1 and Lib 2 are in the same site collection.

Comment: Whether the two document libraries on the same site collection or on the different site collections?

Comment: Same site collection.  I'll edit my original post.

Answer (score 0):

This is news to me, but you can set [$List.ParserDisabled](https://www.sharepointed.com/2021/03/sharepoint-online-and-copied-metadata/) at the library level.  Doing this will eliminate metadata being copied from source documents.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing.